# How to make sure that a function doesn't get called using Mock in a Django Application

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I've already browsed through the mock documentations, and i've seen some examples where mock has been used. But, being a newbie, i find it hard to use mock in my tests.

**`test_scoring.py`** - I am creating a test to make sure that a function DOES NOT get called whenever i create an item.

The function **`compute_score()`** that i'd like to mock is part of a class **`HistoryItem`**.

What i got so far is this :

```
#test_scoring.py

@mock.patch('monitor.report.history_item.HistoryItem.compute_score')
def test_save_device_report(self):
    ....
    result = factory.create_history_item(jsn)
    # If the mocked method gets called after the above function is used, then there should be an error.
```

So, how do I mock the method? I'm quite confused on how to use it, because there are different ways in the resources i found.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the patch method as a decorator, you need to specify a second parameter to your test function:

```
@mock.patch('monitor.report.history_item.HistoryItem.compute_score')
def test_save_device_report(self, my_mock_compute_score):
    ....
    # Assuming the compute_score method will return an integer
    my_mock_compute_score.return_value = 10

    result = factory.create_history_item(jsn)
    # Then simulate the call.
    score = result.compute_score() # This call could not be necessary if the previous
                                   # call (create_history_item) make this call for you.

    # Assert method was called once
    my_mock_compute_score.assert_called_once()
    # Also you can assert that score is equal to 10
    self.assertEqual(score, 10)
```

Note that the mocks should be used only when you've tested the patched method or object in another test.

Where to patch? -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

**Edit**

This patch is gonna to avoid a real call to `compute_score()`. However, after reread your post I can see you want to assert your function doesn't get called.

Hopefully, the `called` attribute is present in every mock you make, so for that you can use:

```
@mock.patch('monitor.report.history_item.HistoryItem.compute_score')
def test_save_device_report(self, my_mock_compute_score):
    ...
    result = factory.create_history_item(jsn)
    self.assertFalse(my_mock_compute_score.called)
    ...
```